# Change the layout of CiviCRM > CiviCase Dashboard > Find Cases

Tags: civicase, display

I've only started trying to change some features of an existing CiviCRM database in a testsystem (using CiviCases). So I am still a beginner, I excuse myself if this is a silly question, and any hint will be appreciated :)

My goal is to change the layout of the search results in Find Cases. Specifically, I want to change the line height. I tried editing this in the CSS file but didn't succeed.

Do you have any hints for me?

Edit: In the civicrm.css, I tried setting the line height for example in this part (the class of the table lines is `even-row` or `odd-row`, among others):

```
.crm-container tr.even-row td,
.crm-container tr.odd-row td,
.crm-container table.display td,
.crm-container table.pagerDisplay td {
  border-color: #efefef;
  border-right: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: How did you tried to add the css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, but I wouldn't edit civicrm.css, I'd make an extension and add it as [described in the dev docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets)

`table.caseSelector tr { line-height: 10em; }`

So e.g. in hook_civicrm_buildForm: `CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyle('table.caseSelector tr { line-height: 10em; }');`

But I don't think it's actually line-height you're looking for since wrapping in the cells would make that look weird. You maybe just want height:

`CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyle('table.caseSelector tr { height: 10em; }');`

But what exactly to use depends why you're trying to change it.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to edit it only because of user-friendliness, so the list of results will not be as long visually

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [civicase v5 extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicase-v5)? It has got nice UI to manage cases.